# why is my state not updated in useEffect?

Tags: reactjs

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
const [gioHangChiTiet, setGioHangChiTiet] = useState([])
const [gioHangSanPham, setGioHangSanPham] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const dataGioHang = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}api/giohangs`, {
                headers: {
                    token: `Bearer ${user.user?.accessToken}`
                }
            })
            console.log(res.data.data.sach)
            setGioHangChiTiet(res.data.data)
            console.log(gioHangChiTiet "it is empty")
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    if (user.user) {
        dataGioHang()
        // console.log(gioHangChiTiet)
    }
}, [user])
```

That is my code. I trying to save gioHangChiTiet with new data but it's always is an empty array. I try console.log this and I think it will work but it's not. But if I change any thing in this code, gioHangChiTiet will update new data and console.log this. Can anyone help me and explain why? Thank you so much. I spent a lot of time figuring out how to solve it :(( . UPDATED : I fixed it. Thanks a lots ( console.log not run because it in useEffect , if i console after useEffect, i will have true value)

Comment: You have to put user in your dependency array

Comment: I put user on my dependency array but it not work.
when i console.log(gioHangChiTiet) it's still an empty array.

Answer (score 0):

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
const [gioHangChiTiet, setGioHangChiTiet] = useState([])
const [gioHangSanPham, setGioHangSanPham] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const dataGioHang = async () => {
        try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}api/giohangs`, {
                headers: {
                    token: `Bearer ${user.user?.accessToken}`
                }
            })
            console.log(res.data.data.sach)
            // setGioHangChiTiet(res.data.data.sach)
            setGioHangChiTiet(res.data.data)
            console.log(gioHangChiTiet)
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
        }
    }
    if (user.user) {
        dataGioHang()
        // console.log(gioHangChiTiet)
    }
}, [user])
```

Add user to your dependency array. Otherwise the useEffect wont be able to check your if statement. If you're using CRA you should get a warning in your terminal.

Comment: I put user on my dependency array but it not work. when i console.log(gioHangChiTiet) after i call dataGioHang() ,it's still an empty array

Answer (score 0):

`useEffect` takes two arguments first one is callback function and second one is dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
// this is callback function
},[ /* this is dependency array */ ])
```

If you want to trigger the callback function every time a state changes you need to pass that state in dependency array.

```
useEffect(() => {
console.log(someState)
},[someState])
```

In above code `someState` will get logged each time it's value changes.

If your dependency array is empty you useEffect callback function will trigger ONLY ONCE.

**In your case if you want trigger callback function on change of `user` state or any other state simply pass it in dependency array.**

Comment: I want to setGioHangChiTiet(res.data.data) in dataGioHang funtion and when i set it and console.log(gioHangChiTiet) It's still empty array. I think it not related to dependency  array.

Answer (score 0):

Can you give this a try:

```
const user = useSelector(state => state.user)
const [gioHangChiTiet, setGioHangChiTiet] = useState([])
const [gioHangSanPham, setGioHangSanPham] = useState([])

useEffect(() => {
    const dataGioHang = new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
    ( async() => { 
          try {
            const res = await axios.get(`${apiUrl}api/giohangs`, {
                headers: {
                    token: `Bearer ${user.user?.accessToken}`
                }
            })
            console.log(res.data.data.sach)
            setGioHangChiTiet(res.data.data.sach)
            setGioHangChiTiet(res.data.data)
            console.log(gioHangChiTiet)
            resolve();
        } catch (error) {
            console.log(error)
            reject()
        }})();
})

    if (user.user) {
         dataGioHang().then(()={ console.log(gioHangChiTiet);
     })
     .catch(() => console.log("Error executing dataGioHang"))
   }
}, [user])
```

Comment: please dont post multiple answers, just edit your old one

Comment: @kevin both answers represent different topics so I thought to leave previous one if anyone finds it useful

Comment: it's not work for me :(( . The console give message "destroy is not a function
    at safelyCallDestroy"

Comment: @NguyễnĐiệp I am really sorry for that I tottaly forgot useEffect callback shouldn't be async. Please give the updated answer a try.